# Editing image with GD before uploading to server

Tags: php, image, upload, gd

I am attempting to add some text to an image with a border before uploading to server. It appears however the way that I have written my code doesn't upload the image. I have checked separately that the upload works and the image manipulation work but together they do not work:

```
$name = "some text";
$target_dir = "uploads/";
//strip filename of clear spaces 
$cleaned = str_replace(' ', '', basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]));
$target_file = $target_dir . $cleaned;
$image = $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"];


$im = imagecreatefromjpeg($image);
$white = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
$font_path = 'uploads/SCRIPTIN.ttf';
$text = "In Memory of " . $name;
imagesetthickness($im, 200);
$black = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);
$x = 0;
$y = 0;
$w = imagesx($im) - 1;
$z = imagesy($im) - 1;
imageline($im, $x, $y, $x, $y+$z, $black);
imageline($im, $x, $y, $x+$w, $y, $black);
imageline($im, $x+$w, $y, $x+$w, $y+$z, $black);
imageline($im, $x, $y+$z, $x+$w ,$y+$z, $black);
imagettftext($im, 200, 0, 20, 300, $white, $font_path, $text);
```

I think it might be related to how I am writing the file to the server:

```
move_uploaded_file(imagejpeg($im), $target_file);
```

Comment: You should use $_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'], this is where the file is actually stored on your server, $_FILES['fileToUpload']['name'] only gives you the original name as it was on users machine. Also, you're not performing any checks on whether or not this is a valid file - this can lead to issues, you shouldn't trust your user. At least perform an extension check and mime type check. This will also allow you to work with image formats other than jpg/jpeg.

Comment: just replace the "move_uuploaded_file" to "imagejpeg($im,$target_file );"

Answer (score 1):

This is a quick draft, but it should work:

Create a file ImageProcessor.php, copy the code, and include it via `require_once`:

```
class ImageProcessor
{
    /** @var string actual file, in our tmp folder on the server */
    private $file;

    /** @var string filename that we are going to save it with */
    private $filename;

    /** @var string the name we are going to write on the image */
    private $name_to_write;

    /** @var resource file resource */
    private $resource = false;

    /** @var string where we are going to save the result */
    public static $save_path = 'images/';

    /** @var array the list of file extensions we're going to allow */
    private $allowed_extensions = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif');

    public function __construct($file, $name_to_write)
    {
        if (!is_array($file) || !isset($file['tmp_name'])) {
            throw new Exception('We are expecting something else');
        }

        $this->file = $file['tmp_name'];
        $this->filename = $file['name'];
        $this->name_to_write = $name_to_write;

        if (!$this->checkFileValidity()) {
            throw new Exception('Invalid file');
        }
    }

    /*
     * Get the file extension in lowercase for further checks
     *
     * @return string
     */
    private function getExtension()
    {
        return strtolower(pathinfo($this->filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
    }

    /*
     * Check whether the file has a valid extension.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    private function checkFileValidity()
    {
        return in_array($this->getExtension(), $this->allowed_extensions);
    }

    /*
     * Create a resource, depending on file's extension
     *
     * @return void
     */
    private function setFileResource()
    {
        switch ($this->getExtension()) {
            case 'jpeg':
            case 'jpg':
                $this->resource = imagecreatefromjpeg($this->file);
            break;

            case 'png':
                $this->resource = imagecreatefrompng($this->file);
            break;

            case 'gif':
                $this->resource = imagecreatefromgif($this->file);
            break;
        }
    }

    /*
     * Process the file - add borders, and writings, and so on.
     * In the last step we're also saving it.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function processFile()
    {
        $this->setFileResource();

        if (!$this->resource) {
            throw new Exception('Invalid file');
        }

        $white = imagecolorallocate($this->resource, 255, 255, 255);
        $font_path = 'uploads/SCRIPTIN.ttf';
        $text = "In Memory of ".$this->name_to_write;

        imagesetthickness($this->resource, 200);
        $black = imagecolorallocate($this->resource, 0, 0, 0);
        $x = 0;
        $y = 0;
        $w = imagesx($im) - 1;
        $z = imagesy($im) - 1;
        imageline($this->resource, $x, $y, $x, $y+$z, $black);
        imageline($this->resource, $x, $y, $x+$w, $y, $black);
        imageline($this->resource, $x+$w, $y, $x+$w, $y+$z, $black);
        imageline($this->resource, $x, $y+$z, $x+$w ,$y+$z, $black);
        imagettftext($this->resource, 200, 0, 20, 300, $white, $font_path, $text);

        return $this->save();
    }

    /*
     * Save the file in $save_path and return the path to the file
     *
     * @return mixed string|bool
     */
    private function save()
    {
        imagejpeg($this->resource, self::$save_path.$this->filename);

        return file_exists(self::$save_path.$this->filename) ? self::$save_path.$this->filename : false;
    }
}
```

And then you call it when you detect that the file has been uploaded:

```
if (isset($_FILES['fileToUpload']) && is_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'])) {
    $processor = new ImageProcessor($_FILES['fileToUpload'], 'John Doe');

    if ($image_path = $processor->processFile()) {
        var_dump($image_path); // this is your new image
    }
}
```

**UPDATED** (forgot to include the name to write on the image)